# Proguard Helloworld Sample App Not Working after Obfuscation

Tags: java, proguard

1) Created a guardsample-0.1.local.jar with com.proguard.sample.HelloWorld.java and executed the jar file for Hello world being printed on the console

2) Installed proguard locally and obfuscated the guardsample-0.1.local.jar

3) Trying to run the obfuscated jar and i get a error as main method not found on decompiled code

4) Used a decompiler to look at classes and i dont see the main method . Please advise

5) Proguard config is simple

```
enter code here

-injars guardsample-0.1.local.jar
-outjars guardsample-0.1.local.out.jar
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\lib\rt.jar'
 -dontoptimize
 -classobfuscationdictionary 
 'C:\PROGUARD\artifcats\obfuscationdictionary.txt'
  -packageobfuscationdictionary 
  'C:\PROGUARD\artifcats\obfuscationdictionary.txt'
 -flattenpackagehierarchy 'C:\PROGUARD\artifcats\obfuscationdictionary.txt'
 -repackageclasses 
 -keepparameternames
  adaptclassstrings
  -keepclasseswithmembers
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep the entry points of the application so that it can be launched by the execution environment. If I understand correctly, you are creating a standard Java program that has a `main(String[])` method? Then you need to add the following rule (see also the ProGuard manual):

```
 -keep class com.proguard.sample.HelloWorld {
    static void main(java.lang.String[]);
 }
```